# unable to access the prestashop webservice via getJSON

Tags: web-services, prestashop, getjson

I am trying to use the webservice prestashop (1.6) to get my product by using the jquery function getJSON() but on the console's browser, I get the following error :

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load
 http://www.pourquoilavie.org/api/products/?ws_key=XXXXXkeyXXXXXXXXX&io_format=JSON.
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
 resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried to add " Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " to the htaccess but without success.

I wonder if there is another way to set a header (except using php with  `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself, I just add  `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on the file dispatcher.php in the webservice folder

Answer (score 3):

In prestashop 1.6 you can try to add this in

```
./prestafolder/webservice/dispatcher.php
```

for security reason, instead of asterisk you can type domain name

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
```

FYI

If you will still have problems or `Unauthorized` message, try to change your url from

```
http://KEYTOKEN@example.com/api/
```

into

```
http://example.com/api/?ws_key=KEYTOKEN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Angular or Similar Frameworks, modify and add the following code according to your environment on the first line of `prestashop_folder/webservice/dispatcher.php` file

```
// Allow from any origin
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]))
{
    // You can decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is something you want to allow, or as we do here, just allow all
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
}
else
{
    //No HTTP_ORIGIN set, so we allow any. You can disallow if needed here
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 600");    // cache for 10 minutes

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS")
{
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD"]))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"); //Make sure you remove those you do not want to support

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    //Just exit with 200 OK with the above headers for OPTIONS method
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me i tried with react app i had to made some modification in dispatcher.php and add for option preflight 200 return

i added in the dispatcher.php header

```
//to access from external browser
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access- 
Control-Request-Headers,Output-Format');
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, DELETE');
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

then modified like this after in the code

```
 if ($method === 'OPTIONS') {
die('200');
ob_end_flush();
}else{
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
....
}
```